# Как запретить вывод постов определенной категории в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование

У меня имеется 2 типа кастомных постов на сайте под Wordpress - Location и Event. Location связан с Event как одно из мета полей (для сортировки). Т.е., например такое-то мероприятие (event) проходит в Москве (Location). Данные Location (привязка к Location Москва) прописываются в мета поле поста Event.

На странице поста Location Москва выводятся все посты Event, которые имеют признак Москва в соответствующем мета поле. Проблема в том, что там выводятся все возможные категории постов Event. Мне нужно запретить одну категорию (категория custom post type) для вывода на этой странице.

Сейчас код такой:

```
$count = 0;
$paged = 1;
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
}
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'event',
'paged' => $paged, 
'meta_query' => array(
 array( 'key' => 'location', 'value' => get_the_ID() ),
),
);
$tmp_query;
global $wp_query;
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$post_ids = array();
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
if ( $template_type == 1) {
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
$the_query->the_post();
echo event();
endwhile;
}
```

Категория постов events имеет вид event_category, ID исключаемой категории 2136.

Comment: Не до конца ясен вопрос, но, чтобы запретить категорию, а точней исключить посты категории, просто добавте к аргументам `tax_query` с соответствующими правилами, советую почитать https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query

Comment: tax_query помог! Спасибо!